# Can't configure p10k using oh my zsh : zsh: command not found: p10k

Tags: themes, oh-my-zsh, hyperterm

I wanted to install the p10k theme in my terminal but I get an error.

```
➜  ~ p10k configure
zsh: command not found: p10k
```

I have no clue on what the issue is.
Thanks for your time :),
Hukyfi

Comment: Could try some solutions there https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/557

Answer (score 28):

Install Powerlevel10k manually.

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git ~/powerlevel10k
echo 'source ~/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme' >>~/.zshrc
```

This method of installation won't make anything slower or otherwise sub-par.

[powerlevel10k manual](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#weird-things-happen-after-typing-source-zshrc)

Answer (score 26):

Most probably this step of cloning `powerlevel10k` is already done:

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git ~/powerlevel10k
```

The problem is in the command mentioned in `powerlevel10k` README file. It should be

```
echo 'source ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme' >>~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 11):

I know it is a bit late (2 years I guess) but your problem is caused by fact you installed p10k going Oh My Zsh's way (from the doc's) but you forgot to do one simple thing.

To set:

```
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"
```

in ~/.zshrc.

Comment: Actually, my problem was an existing line `ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"` several lines below

Comment: Thanks for comment. In my case, which was very similar to Hukify's, what I wrote helped. But your is kinda similar too. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Also note the ZSH_THEME needs to be set before `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` in your .zshrc

Answer (score 2):

Also typing (below) should show the prompt after you've made the edit in .rc file.

```
$ exec zsh
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and already installed Powerlevel10k correctly. My problem was I had two `ZSH_THEME` variables with **different** values (a default ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell" and the new ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k") in my .zshrc file. I deleted the `ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"` line (then `source .zshrc`) and it worked.

Comment: Nice, thanks for sharing with us. I'm certain it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did add `ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"` at the end of `~/.zshrc` and it was producing the same error as for question author.

Make sure you add it before `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` line in the `~/.zshrc`